# Print content of deep lists?

Tags: java, list

It there any library/framework that can print the content of a list with class hierarchy?
I have some auto-generated POJOs from an XML Webservice. The lists may be 5-10 classes deep.

How can I print out the full content of the most parent element, without having to implement `toString()` in every of my POJOs? Especially, as they may get regenerated later.
Is there any library that usese reflection or something to just print out the list content to the deepst level?

Comment: You may use Reflection to get the fields and the class.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6807798/1121633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JAXB.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
javax.xml.bind.JAXB.marshal(pojo, stream);
System.out.println(stream.toString("UTF-8"));
```