# ToString Any Complex Collection in Java

Tags: java

Maybe I'm forgetting something, but I need a simple utility method to print the contents of any complex data structure involving Strings, rather than references, such as `Enumeration<String>`, `HashMap<String,String[]>`, etc.

It can include any combination of Arrays, Lists, Enumerations, etc.

e.g.:

```
HttpServletRequest request;
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameters();
return params.toString(); 
// returns java.util.Collections$3@246f8103
```

or

```
Map<String,String[]> requestParamMap = request.getParameterMap();
return requestParamMap.toString(); 
// returns {function=[Ljava.lang.String;@4f9ffa55, jsessionId=[Ljava.lang.String;@4abf9318}
```

Comment: Try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443730/java-tostring-using-reflection

Comment: weird, any collections should invoke content's `toString()`. and [String, should return a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString--)

Comment: If you use a `List` instead of an `Array`, the `Map` will print everything correctly.  `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: There isn't an arbitrary way to do that for any complex data structure.