# Trying to run a method with a scanner

Tags: java

I'm doing a simple school project but I'm stuck on something that's probably really simple.

The program is basically for a "bank owner" who has access to people's accounts and the ability to create multiple accounts.

All I need to do is allow the user to input the name of the account which they'd like to get information on

Assume I made a new account as follows:

```
static Account account01 = new Account( "Account 1" , 25.0 );
```

where "Account1" is the name of the account and "25.0" is the balance, in dollars.

Now I have the following code

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the account that you want to print the    balance of");
    String nameInput = scan.nextLine();
    nameInput.toString();
```

I want to run the toString method for account01 which prints the account balance, but how do I do that? I tried doing nameInput.toString(); but that just prints the name I typed in. I need to substitute nameInput with the name of the account entered.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Get a list of the accounts, 2. search for the account maching the given name, 3. print account.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: No arrays or collection are allowed in this project. I was thinking of doing that but it's not allowed.

Comment: There is no way to get the account from a string without searching a collection of accounts or using reflection (which is probably not something you've learned)

Comment: can't you just have a getter method which returns account balance ?

Comment: @FaforeTunde - OP would still need to get the Account object instance from the input.

Comment: Yes I do have a getBal() method which returns the balance, but I still need to find a way to use the string text as the name of the class.

Comment: @Bardya yes that is what I was thinking. So if there is a way to loop through your accounts (which I'm not sure there is) then you can lookup each of their properties.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking if you can (somehow) have the user enter the name of a *variable*.  That is next to impossible (for a local variable) and almost certainly NOT what your instructor envisages.

That leaves you with using collections (preferable) or arrays ... or hard-wiring the accounts into the code, which seems to be a contradiction of your requirements.

> "No arrays or collection are allowed in this project."

That's an extraordinary restriction<sup>1</sup>, given the requirement that the bank manager can create multiple accounts.  (I guess, it is possible that you are suppose to put the information into a database and access it via JDBC, but that's not a simple exercise.)

I strongly suspect that either you have *misunderstood* the requirements, or that you haven't explained them to us properly.

---

<sup>1 - It is not impossible to achieve though.  You could implement your own list or array type from scratch.  Just ... a lot of work, and it seems to be "beside the point* in the context of your assignment, from what I can make out.</sup>

Comment: Afaik you can't implement an array-like type without arrays in java. The closest you can get is a linked list or a binary tree.

Comment: @hege_hegedus - That's what I meant.  A linked list or tree or something  similar could be used to simulate an array .... inefficiently.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the `toString()` of you defined `Account` class, to print all attribute values:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
public String toString() {
   return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
}
```

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/443768/452708)

You can override `toString()` to print your required value.

But searching for Account based on Name would require you to store the Account Objects in some Collection.

Comment: OP says `toString` is already implemented. You searching statement is more of a comment than an answer, and in the comments it is mentioned collections can't be used.

Comment: @cricket_007 `toString()` in the code is invoked on  `String nameInput` & not on Account class(to which I was pointing at).
//logic
Override `toString()` to print Balance 
Loop through all the objects based on no. of Account Object created(No Collection mean limited no. of objects created).
Check for scanner value against each Account Name
Invoke `toString()`

Comment: I understand the problem. How exactly do you loop over all the Account objects without a collection? Also, in the post *I want to run the toString method for account01 which prints the account balance*, which I took to imply `toString()` is already defined in Account

Comment: @cricket_007 , looping over objects would require to have custom implementation to manage indices of object created.  Stephen mentions about custom implementation of List or Array [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34247818/452708)