# Java & SQL - ResultSet with class' toString() method

Tags: java, sql, resultset, tostring

I have a class called Item, which - besides everything else as usual - defines the toString method like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + "]";
}
```

Then I have an SQL connector for dumping all items in the table like this:

```
public ArrayList<Item> dumpAll() {
        ArrayList<Item> dump = new ArrayList<Item>();
        connectDB();
        try {
            result = connectDB().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Items").executeQuery();
            if (result != null) {
                connectDB().close();
                while (result.next()) {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.toString();
                    dump.add(item);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Query failed.");
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dump;
    }
```

`connectDB();` is working fine. When I call the toString method elsewhere, I can see a result like this:

```
Item [id=0, name=null, type=null]
```

This line is repeated as many times as I have items in the table, i.e. I have 50 items; I get 50 lines showing zeroes and nulls. The format is exactly as I want it but obviusly the results are not. I think I'm missing something obvious handling the `result`, but trying to debug with `String itm = result.toString();`, `Item.equals(result.toString());` and so on hasn't worked out.

Comment: You create an empty item, call `toString()` on it (for no effect), then add it to a list. You're left with a list of empty items. Surprised?

Comment: So after creating a new `Item`, I am to `item.xxxx(result.yyyy));`, but... what?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

It's your

```
Item item = new Item();
```

line. That says: "initialise an Item with NOTHING!" So of course you have empty objects. It should be:

```
Item item = new Item(result.getInt(0), result.getString(1), result.getString(2));
```

Or whatever column names you gave them in the SQL table.

---

### Side note

It's bad practice to allow invalid objects. You shouldn't HAVE a default constructor for your Item object, because there should never be an Item object with invalid data. Trust me when I say it makes everything easier in the long run.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261585/should-a-getter-throw-an-exception-if-its-object-has-invalid-state

---

### Experimental solution

If you **must** use the SQL columns automatically (without having to specify each column), it's possible using reflection, but it's fairly brittle. It only works if the following is satisfied:

- The property names on the Java object are exactly the same as the SQL columns
- The property types on the Java object are the default types from ResultSet (primitives to Wrapper classes are ok)

The reflection part can be put into a base class to be extended elsewhere. Here I've called it SimpleSQL. (This has the distinct feeling that I'm being too clever with this answer. I take no responsibility for this code; it's purely being presented as a "you **could** do this" scenario)

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class SimpleSQL {

    public SimpleSQL(ResultSet result) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        for (Field f: getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            // Get the field type name, converting the first character to uppercase
            String fTypNam = f.getType().getSimpleName();
            fTypNam = fTypNam.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + fTypNam.substring(1);

            // Get an object that represents each of the methods we want to call
            Method getM = result.getClass().getMethod("get" + fTypNam, String.class);
            Method setM = f.getClass().getMethod("set", Object.class, Object.class);

            // Set the property of this object using the field object's set
            //  and the ResultSet's get.
            setM.invoke(f, this, getM.invoke(result, f.getName()));
            // For a hypothetical 'id' field that is an int, this is equivalent to:
            //   this.id = result.getInt("id");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = getClass().getName()+"[";
        try {
            Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            result += fields[0].getName() + ": " + fields[0].get(this);
            for(int i = 1; i < fields.length; ++i) {
                result += ", " + fields[i].getName() + ": " + fields[i].get(this);
            }
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            // This happens if the field is private.
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        result += "]";
        return result;
    }
}
```

(see [more on toString and reflection here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443730/java-tostring-using-reflection). tl;dr, the Apache Commons library provides a ReflectionToStringBuilder class for a better version of my toString())

Then you can just define your Item as:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Item extends SimpleSQL {
    protected int id;
    protected String name;
    protected String description;

    public Item(ResultSet result) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        super(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the approach, but say that my table would have 200 columns with `int`s and `double`s and such mixed, would I have to `get` _every_ one of them separately when I have a method toString() to dump all of them out at once?

Comment: What I'm asking is that there's no way to utilize (an automatically generated) `toString()` method which would help avoid all the manual `get`s?

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what the result.next() is doing.

Comment: The result set object has some temporary memory area for a single row of the returned results. When you call result.next() it grabs the next row of the response, and puts it in this temporary memory. Then, when you call `result.getString(0)`, you are grabbing the value in the first column of the the loaded row and parsing it as a string. The 'manual `get`s' are surely not that big a deal; you only have to specify what to do per-row.

Comment: Oh, sorry you mentioned many rows. Yes, if you have 200 columns, then you would have to manually `get` each one. However, really, I can't imagine a well-designed use case that requires that many columns for a single object. You should consider which ones you **REALLY** need and only use those. If you **really** do need 200 of them, then the way Java is designed, then you should be creating an object that has 200 properties and passing through 200 parameters.

Comment: That explains the behavior, thanks. So basically my question is useless since it cannot be answered.

Comment: Thinking on it further, it should be possible to use reflection to automatically fill the properties into such an object....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130192/discussion-between-multihunter-and-lapingultah).

Answer (score 1):

Your Item class should have `getters()`, `setters()`, `constructor()`, and the `toString()` methode like this:

```
public class Item {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Item(int id, String name, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    //...Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }
}
```

So after that you should to create an object like this:

```
while (result.next()) {
    Item item = new Item(result.getInt("id"), result.getString("name"), result.getString("type"));
    item.toString();
}
```

Hope this can help you.